# a little Confusion with List View Columns and other code?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

i am working on inventory software, now I've asked product quantity and product price from the user in text boxes and have added them in list view, each time i click on Add Product button the text boxes simply go blank and data goes in list view, i want to grand total the price of each product (values in Product Price column) and i want to add all the prices in the list view the code for adding values in list view is :

```
  private void btnAddProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int totalPrice = 0;
            int val1, val2;
            string totalp;           


             val1 = Convert.ToInt32(txtProductPrice.Text);
             val2 = Convert.ToInt32(txtProductQuantity.Text);
             totalPrice = val1 * val2;

             totalp = Convert.ToString(totalPrice);


            lvProductInfo.Items.Add(""); //  QuestionID 
            lvProductInfo.Items[lvProductInfo.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(txtProdcutCode.Text); //Question
            lvProductInfo.Items[lvProductInfo.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(txtProductQuantity.Text); //Option1
            lvProductInfo.Items[lvProductInfo.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(txtProductPrice.Text); //Option2
            lvProductInfo.Items[lvProductInfo.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(totalp); //Option3


            txtProdcutCode.Clear();
            txtProductQuantity.Clear();
            txtProductPrice.Clear();
            txtCashRecived.Clear();



            txtProdcutCode.Focus();


        }
```

### now there are two ways to do this:

#### 1) either i capture the value of totalp each time and add it in the previous one(means 2nd time it will be added to the first one)

#### 2) or i pick the value from list view and add them all (pick out all values from price columns) ###

but sadly i am not able to do it correctly, can any one help me out how can i do it?? any suggestions would be appreciated! thanks.

Comment: your problem is that you are reinitializing `totalp` each time a product is clicked on.  Make `totalp` and/or `totalprice` a class level variable instead of a method level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a class for an inventory line item that contains the product code, quantity, and price. Keep a list of those objects as they get added to the list view.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could refresh the total every time an item is added, like this. **Be warned, this could slow your program down if you have a very long list of items.**

```
int totalPrice = 0;    
foreach (ListViewItem item in lvProductInfo.Items)
{
    int price = 0;
    if (double.TryParse(item.SubItems[2].Text, out price))
        totalPrice += price;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private Int32 cumPrice = 0;

totalp = Convert.ToString(totalPrice);  
cumPrice +=  totalp;     
lvProductInfo.Items[lvProductInfo.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(cumPrice.ToString());
```